# Sendgrid and laravel 5.1 store inbound attachments

Tags: php, laravel-5, sendgrid

I'm currently using Laravel and sendgrid in an application of mine.

I want to be able to receive emails with attachements and store them on the server. But the problem here is, HOW should I do this? I currently have a code written, but that code isn't working at all. I can receive the emails, but it doesn't store the attachments. Can someone help me out?

Here is the code I currently have:

```
public function ReceiveMail(Request $request)
    {
     //inserting the email into the database

      // getting all of the post data
      $files = $request->get('attachments');
      // Making counting of uploaded images
      $file_count = count($files);

      //var_dump($files);
      //die;

      if($file_count > 0){
        foreach($files as $key=>$value) {
          $attachment[] = $value;

          $destinationPath = 'public/uploads/pictures/rallypodium/website/mail/attachments/';
          $extension = $attachment->getClientOriginalExtension();
          $filename = $attachment->getClientOriginalName();
          $uploadSuccess = $attachment->move($destinationPath, $filename.$extension);
        }
      }

      return '250';
    }
```

Comment: Robin can you share the code on how you are receiving the emails? It would help me out a lot as im trying to get my application to receive and parse the emails! Thanks.

Comment: It's a form post method.

Comment: Are you making api requests to sendgrid or letting them do the post request to you?

Comment: They do a form post to your specified url

Comment: Yeah i followed their instructions but nothing gets logged in the activity log on their side, everything is whitelisted and domains are setup properly, Do you know if they log failed parse attempts as its somewhat difficult to debug my scenario when they don't give me any clue to if the post request has sent / failed or not!

Comment: Create a question about it and paste the link here or send it to me.